# Trying to step out of this loop

Tags: c++

I'm sorry if the code looks sloppy. I've only learned some loops and if checks so far in the book. I would like to code to step out of the loop. I've tried using break and then I tried with this loop.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double smallest = 0;
    double largest = 0;
    double x = 0;
    string measure = " ";
    double sum = 0;
    vector<double> meters;
    bool leave = false;

    if (!leave)
    {
    while(cin>>x>>measure)
    {

        if (x < largest)
            smallest = x;
        else
            largest = x;

        if ( x == 'x')
            leave = true;

        cout << "You typed " << x << " Smallest number so far: " << smallest << " Largest number so far: " << largest << endl;

        if(measure == "in") //inches
        {
            cout << "You wanted inches? : " << x << " inches" << endl;
            cout << "That also happens to be : " << x * 2.54 << " cm" << endl; // inches to cm
            sum += x * 0.0254;
            meters.push_back(sum);
            cout << "Meters so far : " << sum << endl;
        }
        else if(measure == "cm") //centimeter
        {
            cout << "You wanted centimeters? : " << x << " centimeter" << endl;
            cout << "That also happens to be : " << x / 100 << " m" << endl; // inches to cm
            sum += x / 100;
            meters.push_back(sum);
            cout << "Meters so far : " << sum << endl;
        }
        else if(measure == "f") //feet
        {
            cout << "You wanted feet? : " << x << " feet" << endl;
            cout << "That also happens to be : " << x * 12 << " inches" << endl; // inches to cm
            sum += x * 0.3048;
            meters.push_back(sum);
            cout << "Meters so far : " << sum << endl;
        }
        else if(measure == "m") //meters
        {
            cout << "You wanted meters? : " << x << " meters" << endl;
            cout << "That also happens to be : " << x * 100 << " cm" << endl; // inches to cm
            sum += x;
            meters.push_back(sum);
            cout << "Meters so far : " << sum << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "error invalid measurement. " << endl;
            keep_window_open();
        }
    }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<meters.size(); ++i)
        cout << meters[i];


    keep_window_open();
}
```

Comment: why `break` doesn't work for you?

Comment: What about the [`break` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break)?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Break just made the whole window close without printing the below for loop.

Comment: There is not printing below the `for` loop. Unless it's in `keep_window_open`? Can you please show that one too?

Comment: `inline void keep_window_open()
{
 cin.clear();
 cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
 char ch;
 cin >> ch;
 return;
}` I didn't write this, the header was part of the book.

Answer (score 3):

You check the `leave` condition *before* the loop, which will of course not work very well. You should check it *inside* the loop.

It can simplest be put into the actual loop condition:

```
while(!leave && cin >> x >> measure) { ... }
```

---

It seems like you want the input to be *either* a number and a string, *or* just a character. That will not work as the variable `x` is a `double` and can't handle strings or characters being input. You should actually get a warning about using a `double` as a character (the `x == 'x'` comparison).

It might be better to do something like

```
std::string input;
while (std::getline(std::cin, input))
{
    std::istringstream is(input);

    // Try to get a number and a string
    if (is >> x >> measure)
    {
        // Got it, do stuff here...
    }
    else
    {
        // Input was not a number and a string, try to get a character
        char ch;
        if (is >> ch && ch == 'x')
            break;  // Exit loop
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Wrong input, have to be a number and a string, or 'x' to exit\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem you're having with the program exiting abruptly is most likely because of this. When the input statement `std::cin >> x >> measure` can't read the input as a number, it will leave the character in the input buffer, so `keep_window_open` (which I guess reads a string or a character) will get that `'x'` and exit immediately.

Comment: `12f
You typed 12 Smallest number so far: 0 Largest number so far: 12
You wanted feet? : 12 feet
That also happens to be : 144 inches
Meters so far : 3.6576
x
Program closes.`

Comment: I'm trying to space my above code properly. I'm sorry I'm a newbie here ><

Comment: @user2442335 Two things: You want input of `'x'` to exit loop and also exit the program, yes? And when you input `'x'` the input statement tries to read it into the variable `x` which is not a string or characters and so the input statement fails. You may want to split the input into two separate statements or get the whole line and parse the input separately.

Comment: @user2442335 Updated my answer with a possible solution

Comment: The solution has things I haven't learned about yet. Is there a more simple solution? I feel like I'm trying to over complicate things.

Comment: @user2442335 I just updated my answer with a *possible* "why" you have a problem, please look at the end of the answer for that. Yes my solution may have things you don't know about yet, but you can't input *either* a number *or* a character without some kind of check. I suggest you check a [good reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) for the things you don't know about.

Comment: I tried taking the keep_window_open() down to see if the loop at the end even prints and it isn't printing.